# PHP & HTML templating style preferences

Tags: php, html, templates

Basically I have two ways for writing something

First:

```
<?php
echo link_to(
  static_image_tag(
    $object->getImageWebPath(),
    array(
      "alt" => $object->getTitle(),
      "width" => "106",
      "height" => "73",
      "class" => 'aaa bbb'
     )
  ),
  url_for('route_name', $object),
  array(
    "class" => "aaa bbb", "title" => $object->getTitle())
  );
?>
```

Second:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('route_name', $object->getLink()); ?>" title="<?php echo $object->getTitle(); ?>" class="aaa bbb">
  <img src="<?php echo map_to_static_domain($image->getWebPath()) . $image->getWebPath(); ?>" class="aaa bbb" alt="echo $image->getTitle()" "width" => "106", "height" => "73" />
</a>
```

Now the one 'million dollar question', which one way you guys use and maybe even why...

Thanks.

Comment: Second method is less eye-sore, Who are your targeted audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dave Vogt you need slapping Smarty is the biggest eye sore of code i have ever seen and it does some stuff so wrongly and uses so much memory its untrue,

Secondly it entirely depends on what your trying to do, if its a template engine your should use the first,

if its just for your web site then use the second

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, both are - humbly said - suboptimal.

I suggest you look into using a dedicated templating engine, such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net).

I do like the programmatic approach, as (in theory) it could force you to produce valid (X)HTML code, but it's tedious to write, and interferes with the principle of separation between logic and presentation.

Comment: @SDave Vogt - Smarty is even worse in terms of optimization - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630714/smarty-the-best-choice